# Why does my sprite flash in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create a main menu just using a sprite. However, when it gets rendered and everything, the sprite flashes quickly. Why is it doing this?

```
@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    texture = new Texture("ui/mainmenu.png");
    mainMenu = new Sprite(texture);
    mainMenu.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    batch.begin();
    mainMenu.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

Comment: Check my answer out. It should solve your problems.

Answer (score 2):

this goes in your render method:

```
batch.begin();
mainMenu.draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

Render is the method that is constantly called, show is only called once when the screen is shown.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however when I put those three lines of code into the render method, I only get a blank screen.

Comment: Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

You have to put it after this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this exact code, things should work. Each frame, you clear your screen, then render your sprite.

```
@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    texture = new Texture("ui/mainmenu.png");
    mainMenu = new Sprite(texture);
    mainMenu.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    //clear screen to black.
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //render sprite
    batch.begin();
    mainMenu.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Render your sprite using orthographic camera. this might work for you

```
OrthographicCamera cam;
@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    cam= new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2,0);
    cam.update();
    texture = new Texture("ui/mainmenu.png");
    mainMenu = new Sprite(texture);
    mainMenu.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    //clear screen to black.
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //render sprite
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();
    mainMenu.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```